# Angular2: Form values not picked up

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I've created this form inside `ngOnInit()` method:

```
this.cardForm = this.fb.group({
    card_number: ['', Validators.required],
    holderName: ['', Validators.required],
    expiry: ['', Validators.required],
    cvc: ['', Validators.required],
    address_line1: ['', Validators.required],
    address_line2: ['', Validators.required],
    address_city: ['', Validators.required],
    address_state: ['', Validators.required],
    address_zip: ['', Validators.required],
    address_country: ['', Validators.required]
  });
```

On my template:

```
<form [formGroup]="cardForm" novalidate="novalidate">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="cardnumber">Card number</label>
    <input 
      type="text"
      name="cardnumber"
      class="input-transparent form-control"
      formControlName="card_number"
      data-mask="9999-9999-9999-9999"
      placeholder="____-____-____-____"
      required="required">
 </div>
```

When I'm trying to get the values of this form, `card_number`, `cvc` and `expiry` are empty.

[image]

As you can see, `cardForm` have several fields. I've to say they are binded in two `<from>` tags on tamplate.

So, `card_number, holderName, expiry and cvc` are binded on first form:

```
<form [formGroup]="cardForm" novalidate="novalidate">
  <input 
    id="card_number"
    type="text"
    name="card_number"
    class="input-transparent form-control"
    formControlName="card_number"...
```

and the other ones are binded on a second `<form>` tag:

```
<form [formGroup]="cardForm" novalidate="novalidate">
  <input 
    id="address_line1"
    type="text"
    name="address_line1"
    class="input-transparent form-control"
    formControlName="address_line1"...
```

I've also tried to create two `formGroup`, and bind them to a each form on template:

```
this.cardForm = this.fb.group({
    card_number: ['', Validators.required],
    holderName: ['', Validators.required],
    expiry: ['', Validators.required],
    cvc: ['', Validators.required]
});
this.detailsForm = this.fb.group({
    address_line1: ['', Validators.required],
    address_line2: ['', Validators.required],
    address_city: ['', Validators.required],
    address_state: ['', Validators.required],
    address_zip: ['', Validators.required],
    address_country: ['', Validators.required]
  });
```

On template:

```
<form [formGroup]="cardForm" novalidate="novalidate">
<form [formGroup]="detailsForm" novalidate="novalidate">
```

Nevertheless:

[image]

Comment: Since other fields bind correctly I'd take a closer look at either naming or masks applied to problematic fields.

Comment: Yes! I've removed `data-mask="9999-9999-9999-9999"` and the value is picked up. Are you able to tell me what do I need to do to solve that?

Comment: Unfortunately the only advise I have is to try and set mask in js code (by using something along the lines of `$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#card_number').mask('9999-9999-9999-9999');
});` or try different mask plugin.

Answer (score 0):

For a similar case I used `patchValue` or `setValue` of that particular formgroup object.

For e.g in `ngOnInit`you can set:

```
 this.cardForm.patchValue({card_number: 'foobar'});
```

Again, if the value changes you can update in similar way.

```
cardDetailsChanged(val){
   this.cardForm.patchValue({card_number: val});
}
```